# Dynamicaly populate Label under Asp .net Formview Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

This Asp.net page which has FormView Control.I am populating the FormView control by Nortwind database product table.But i wanted to populate a label dynamicaly inside the formview control.so the designer .cs file will not updated with the label .Also attached the Code behind.I tried with FindControl.but it always gives me Null Exception.

Codebehind file

```
protected void DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (ProductsFormView.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
            {
                TextBox ProductNameTextBox = ProductsFormView.FindControl("ProductNameTextBox1") as TextBox;
                ProductNameTextBox.Text = "Hello";
                Label lblSubmit = ProductsFormView.FindControl("lblSubmit") as Label;
                lblSubmit.Text = "HI";
            }
        }
```

**Aspx.page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>FormView Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <h3>FormView Example</h3>
        <table cellspacing="10"> 
          <tr>               
            <td valign="top">



              <asp:FormView ID="ProductsFormView"
                DataSourceID="ProductsSqlDataSource"
                AllowPaging="True"
                  DefaultMode="Insert"
                runat="server" DataKeyNames="ProductID" OnDataBound="DataBound">

                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      ProductID:
                      <asp:Label ID="ProductIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />
                      <br />
                      ProductName:
                      <asp:TextBox ID="ProductNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductName") %>' />
                      <br />
                      CategoryID:
                      <asp:TextBox ID="CategoryIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CategoryID") %>' />
                      <br />
                      QuantityPerUnit:
                      <asp:TextBox ID="QuantityPerUnitTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QuantityPerUnit") %>' />
                      <br />
                      UnitPrice:
                      <asp:TextBox ID="UnitPriceTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UnitPrice") %>' />
                      <br />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="ProductNameTextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                      <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                      &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                  <asp:Label ID="lblSubmit" runat="server" Text=" "></asp:Label>
                  </EditItemTemplate>

                <HeaderStyle forecolor="white" backcolor="Blue" />                

                  <InsertItemTemplate>
                      ProductName:
                      <asp:TextBox ID="ProductNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductName") %>' />
                      <br />
                      CategoryID:
                      <asp:TextBox ID="CategoryIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CategoryID") %>' />
                      <br />
                      QuantityPerUnit:
                      <asp:TextBox ID="QuantityPerUnitTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QuantityPerUnit") %>' />
                      <br />
                      UnitPrice:
                      <asp:TextBox ID="UnitPriceTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UnitPrice") %>' />
                      <br />
                      <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                      &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                  </InsertItemTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    ProductID:
                    <asp:Label ID="ProductIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ProductName:
                    <asp:Label ID="ProductNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductName") %>' />
                    <br />
                    CategoryID:
                    <asp:Label ID="CategoryIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CategoryID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    QuantityPerUnit:
                    <asp:Label ID="QuantityPerUnitLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QuantityPerUnit") %>' />
                    <br />
                    UnitPrice:
                    <asp:Label ID="UnitPriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UnitPrice") %>' />
                    <br />
                </ItemTemplate>

                <PagerTemplate>
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td><asp:LinkButton ID="FirstButton" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="First" Text="<<" RunAt="server"/></td>
                      <td><asp:LinkButton ID="PrevButton"  CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev"  Text="<"  RunAt="server"/></td>
                      <td><asp:LinkButton ID="NextButton"  CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next"  Text=">"  RunAt="server"/></td>
                      <td><asp:LinkButton ID="LastButton"  CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Last"  Text=">>" RunAt="server"/></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </PagerTemplate>

              </asp:FormView>

            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ProductsSqlDataSource" 
          SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [ProductName], [CategoryID], [QuantityPerUnit], [UnitPrice] FROM [Products]" 
          connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" 
          RunAt="server"/>

      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason you are using InsertItemTemplate Items? I think you need to use ProductNameLabel which is in Item template..

Comment: i wanted to populate this label text dynamicaly<asp:Label ID="lblSubmit" runat="server" Text=" "></asp:Label>

Comment: even i check all the mode but I m not able to find the label.It always return as Null( FormViewMode.ReadOnly ,edit mode,insert mode)

Comment: I don't see the <asp:Label ID="lblSubmit" runat="server" Text=" "></asp:Label> in the InsertItemTemplate

Comment: its in edit item template.but i wanted to populate while page Load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use the Databound event, if you want to modify something that's only in the EditItemTemplate, you should use the ModeChanged event.  That way you can check to make sure that the new mode is going to be "Edit" (so you know the control will exist).

You'll need to handle the event in your markup:

```
<asp:FormView ID="ProductsFormView" DataSourceID="ProductsSqlDataSource"
    AllowPaging="True" DefaultMode="Insert" runat="server" 
    DataKeyNames="ProductID" OnDataBound="DataBound" 
    OnModeChanged="ProductsFormView_ModeChanged">
```

And then the actual event code would look like this:

```
protected void ProductsFormView_ModeChanged(Object sender, FormViewModeEventArgs e)
{
    if(ProductsFormView.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
    {
        Label lblSubmit = (Label)ProductsFormView.FindControl("lblSubmit");
        lblSubmit.Text = "Hi!";
    }
}
```

*I know this is kind of an old-ish question, but I figured it couldn't hurt to post an answer*